# Primary source for recovery time equation?

Tags: adsorption

I am working with nanostructure used as gas sensor/filters. Reading the literature, I found that one of the properties that can be calculated to characterize the (re)usability of a sensor is the recovery time, $\tau$. The formula used to calculate $\tau$ is described as:

$$\tau = \nu^{-1}_0 exp (-E_{ads}/k_BT),\tag{1}$$

where $\nu_0$ is the frequency of the ultraviolet radiation used, $E_{ads}$ is the absorption energy, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $T$ is the system temperature.

I tracked around 23-25 papers about how (1) was obtained. In all of them, I only found, without any further citations or citations to other papers that used the same justification:

> The recovery time can be predicted from the following formula of transition theory:
> $\tau = \nu^{-1}_0 exp (-E_{ads}/k_BT),\tag{1}$

**Question: Do you know a primary source for equation (1)?**

Comment: Not any primary source, but I wonder if we can give a justification in line with rate constant law from transition state theory. The rate constant (with unit $\mathrm{Hz}$), $k=A\,\exp{(-E/k_BT)}$. Recovery time should be inversely related with the rate constant. So, $\tau=1/k=A^{-1}\,\exp{(E/k_BT)}$. This seem to work if activation energy $(E_a)$ and adsorption energy $(E_{ads})$ are negative of each-other!

Comment: So, the transition here can be seen as adsorbed/free? Also, which should be the meaning of $A$?

Comment: @Camps, usually this equation is referred to as Van’t-Hoff-Arrhenius expression https://doi.org/10.1515/zpch-1889-0408. Regarding  $\nu^{-1}_0$, it is vibrational frequency of the initial state along the reaction coordinate, which can be described with transition state theory and collision theory. For simplicity, the vibrational frequency usually considered to be constant based solely on the transition state theory. However, when exploring collision theory, it is crucial to acknowledge the significance of both space and volume as they actively influence the frequency of molecular collisions.